# How to make a color from a number

Tags: python, colors

I have a function that returns a float from 0 to 255. I would like to make a gradient in red color from this, but I need a string in "#FFFFFF" format. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use:

```
"#%02X0000" % x
```

Comment: I'm now getting "not all arguments converted during string formatting" error. Tryed putting numbers instead of x, rounding x, truncating it, still the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should be: "#%02X0000" % x (I.e. the "%" is missing).

Answer (score 3):

```
def rgbtohex(r,g,b):
    return "#%02X%02X%02X" % (r,g,b)
```